# how to rotate a circular image button on its own axis in android app?

Tags: android, animation, rotation, imagebutton

I have the following animation code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate

android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:repeatCount="100"
android:duration="1000" />

</set>
```

//imageButton layout code

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/anime"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/start"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:paddingLeft="10dip"
android:paddingTop="150dip"
android:paddingBottom="10dip"
android:paddingRight="10dip"
android:background="@null"
>
</ImageButton>
```

However, my circular image button is not rotating on its own axis. Rather, its following a circular path. Can anyone kindly help me out fix this animation ?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps it's something to do with the way you have scaleMode defined. Or how you have placed the imagebutton in the layout. It'd be good to see this code.

Comment: @CaspNZ : did add the layout code and all. Can you kindly suggest anything ?

Comment: Maybe the irregular padding is affecting the pivot calculation? What happens if you set all padding to be the same?

Comment: @aromero : thanks.. that works totally cooooooooooooollll :D:D:D:D...

Comment: Let me write an answer for that

Answer (score 2):

The pivot calculation in the animation is taking into account the padding of the ImageView. Since the padding is irregular (the top padding is different from the rest of the sides) the pivot of the animation is not aligned with the real center of your image.

Answer (score 0):

the padding for the `imagebutton` should be uniform.